MariaDB windows client : Plugin mysql_clear_password could not be loaded from command line
I've downloaded mysql for windows from MariaDB
But how can I load this plugin for the mysql command ?
I also tried to set LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN=y but this didn't work
C:\Program Files\MariaDB 11.3\bin>mysql -h localhost -P 43222 -u username -p
Enter password: *******
ERROR 1045 (28000): Plugin mysql_clear_password could not be loaded: Le module spécifié est introuvable. Library path is 'mysql_clear_password.dll'

C:\Program Files\MariaDB 11.3\bin>dir ..\lib\plugin\*clear*
 ...
15/02/2024  11:41            27 136 mysql_clear_password.dll
    
C:\Program Files\MariaDB 11.3\bin>


try mysql plugin-dir="C:\Program Files\MariaDB 11.3\lib\plugin" ....

thak you @danblack, with hiphens it works but I always get a 1045, despite all is ok with heidisql locally for example, strange.
C:\Windows\system32>mysql --plugin-dir="C:\Program Files\MariaDB 11.3\lib\plugin" -h localhost -P 43222 -u username -p Enter password: ** ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'tunnel-server' (using password: YES)
